# Set enabled property of textbox to false and set the forecolor to white

Tags: vb.net

I am using windows forms. The default forecolor of a textbox1.enabled = false is gray, how can I change it to white?

Comment: WinForms? WebForms?...something else?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I am using windows forms. Thanks.

Comment: I've written an article on the topic over at www.Experts-Exchange.com: [A New Approach for Custom Colors in a Disabled VB.Net WinForms TextBox](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10842/A-New-Approach-for-Custom-Colors-in-a-Disabled-VB-Net-WinForms-TextBox.html)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Comment: @thewisegod, I am stil not finding the answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

From my article at Experts-Exchange:

[A New Approach for Custom Colors in a Disabled VB.Net WinForms TextBox](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10842/A-New-Approach-for-Custom-Colors-in-a-Disabled-VB-Net-WinForms-TextBox.html)

Here's the `DisTextBox` class:

```
Public Class DisTextBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Private _ForeColorBackup As Color
    Private _BackColorBackup As Color
    Private _ColorsSaved As Boolean = False
    Private _SettingColors As Boolean = False

    Private _BackColorDisabled As Color = SystemColors.Control
    Private _ForeColorDisabled As Color = SystemColors.WindowText

    Private Const WM_ENABLE As Integer = &HA

    Private Sub DisTextBox_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
        If Not Me._ColorsSaved AndAlso Me.Visible Then
            ' Save the ForeColor/BackColor so we can switch back to them later
            _ForeColorBackup = Me.ForeColor
            _BackColorBackup = Me.BackColor
            _ColorsSaved = True

            If Not Me.Enabled Then ' If the window starts out in a Disabled state...
                ' Force the TextBox to initialize properly in an Enabled state,
                ' then switch it back to a Disabled state
                Me.Enabled = True
                Me.Enabled = False
            End If

            SetColors() ' Change to the Enabled/Disabled colors specified by the user
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnForeColorChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnForeColorChanged(e)

        ' If the color is being set from OUTSIDE our control,
        ' then save the current ForeColor and set the specified color
        If Not _SettingColors Then
            _ForeColorBackup = Me.ForeColor
            SetColors()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnBackColorChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnBackColorChanged(e)

        ' If the color is being set from OUTSIDE our control,
        ' then save the current BackColor and set the specified color
        If Not _SettingColors Then
            _BackColorBackup = Me.BackColor
            SetColors()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetColors()
        ' Don't change colors until the original ones have been saved,
        ' since we would lose what the original Enabled colors are supposed to be
        If _ColorsSaved Then
            _SettingColors = True
            If Me.Enabled Then
                Me.ForeColor = Me._ForeColorBackup
                Me.BackColor = Me._BackColorBackup
            Else
                Me.ForeColor = Me.ForeColorDisabled
                Me.BackColor = Me.BackColorDisabled
            End If
            _SettingColors = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnEnabledChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnEnabledChanged(e)

        SetColors() ' change colors whenever the Enabled() state changes
    End Sub

    Public Property BackColorDisabled() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return _BackColorDisabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As System.Drawing.Color)
            If Not Value.Equals(Color.Empty) Then
                _BackColorDisabled = Value
            End If
            SetColors()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ForeColorDisabled() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return _ForeColorDisabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As System.Drawing.Color)
            If Not Value.Equals(Color.Empty) Then
                _ForeColorDisabled = Value
            End If
            SetColors()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
            If Not Me.Enabled Then ' If the window starts out in a disabled state...
                ' Prevent window being initialized in a disabled state:
                Me.Enabled = True ' temporary ENABLED state
                cp = MyBase.CreateParams ' create window in ENABLED state
                Me.Enabled = False ' toggle it back to DISABLED state 
            Else
                cp = MyBase.CreateParams
            End If
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_ENABLE
                ' Prevent the message from reaching the control,
                ' so the colors don't get changed by the default procedure.
                Exit Sub ' <-- suppress WM_ENABLE message

        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Compile and you should get the new control at the top of your ToolBox.  Place a DisTextBox control and your form and set the `BackColorDisabled` property to White.  Now the BackColor should stay white when you disable it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Enabled = Not TextBox1.Enabled
    DisTextBox1.Enabled = Not DisTextBox1.Enabled

    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Enabled.ToString
    Label2.Text = DisTextBox1.Enabled.ToString
End Sub
```

Screenshots...regular `TextBox` on top; the `DisTextBox` on the bottom.

Enabled:

[image: The DisTextBox while Enabled]

Disabled:

[image: The DisTextBox while Disabled with the BackColorDisabled Property set to White]

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If WinForms do this:

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_EnabledChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

and then on Form_Load do this:

```
TextBox1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. My tag is vb.net. :(

Comment: I can't see new textbox in the toolbox, does the name of it is `WhiteForegroundTextbox`?

Comment: You only need this if you are using WebForms, I specified this in my answer. Now that I see you are using WinForms you use the code above, because WinForms has an EnabledChanged event.

Comment: This does not work for me: Windows 10, VS Community 2015.  TextBox disables, but the color does not change to white.  Have you tested this in WinForms?...

Comment: Yes, this should work on Windows 10 and WinForms. You cannot just copy and paste the EnabledChanged event method, you have to select the TextBox in the designer and then go into properties click the events button(the lightning bolt) and then find the EnabledChanged event and double click it and it will add the event to your code behind and then you paste in YourTextBoxName.ForeColor = Color.White.

Comment: I tested and it did not work.  My code had the `Handles` clause on the end of the EnabledChanged() event.  You're saying it "should" work.  Again, have you **tested** this yourself.  If successful, please report back your environment and possibly a screenshot...

Comment: I've absolutely tested this myself. What's so hard to understand about this code. The fact that you had a handles clause at the end suggests that you are not doing things correctly.